# How to use "field" with rationals?

Tags: coq

Can anybody tell me why the tactic "field" does not work when I try to prove the following goal involving rationals?

```
nat_to_Q 3 * nat_to_Q n * nat_to_Q n + nat_to_Q 3 * nat_to_Q n +
nat_to_Q 3 * nat_to_Q n + nat_to_Q 3 + nat_to_Q 3 * nat_to_Q n + 
nat_to_Q 3 + nat_to_Q n * nat_to_Q n * nat_to_Q n + nat_to_Q n * nat_to_Q n +
nat_to_Q n * nat_to_Q n * nat_to_Q 2 + nat_to_Q n * nat_to_Q 2 ==
nat_to_Q 3 * nat_to_Q n * nat_to_Q n * nat_to_Q n +
nat_to_Q 6 * nat_to_Q n * nat_to_Q n + nat_to_Q 11 * nat_to_Q n + 
nat_to_Q 6
```

Note: n is nat and nat_to_Q is (Z.of_nat n # Pos.of_nat 1).

Thanks a lot,
Marcus.

Answer (score 2):

Let's remove the coercions to make this easier to read:

```
3 * n * n + 3 * n +
    3 * n + 3 * n +
        3 + n * n * n + n * n +
n * n * 2 + n * 2 ==
3 * n * n * n + 
6 * n * n + 11 * n + 6
```

Now we can see the issue: the goal does not hold. The 3rd order coefficient on the left-hand side is 1, but on the right-hand side it is 3.

Comment: Thanks Arthur, I really missed that. However, even after the correction (the 3 should be removed on the right-hand side) the tactic "ring" won´t work. Is there something else that I am missing here? The message I get is "Tactic failure: not a valid ring equation".

Comment: There are other issues as well; for instance, the constant term is 3 on the left-hand side, but 6 on the right-hand side.  You might also need to unfold `nat_to_Q` before calling `field`.

Comment: I finally realized that Coq is unable to guess certain things, such as nat_to_Q 6 == nat_to_Q 3 + nat_to_Q 3. Thus, I simplified the literals, used some extra lemmas on nat_to_Q and now ring works fine, Thanks a lot for the insights.